# How to put table of contents at the beginning of each chapter?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, chapters

How can i have such a format in every chapter in my thesis. More specifically i would like this table of contents for each chapter depending on its subsections.[image]

Comment: Hi! There are some ways and packages for that. But please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and make a suitable solution when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The `minitoc` package is designed for this

Comment: Package `etoc` would be an alternative to `minitoc`.